# How to decompose cohort data?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to decompose cohort data into time series for further analysis. I'm imagining the algorithm pretty well, but my code doesn't work at all.

The input data in `df` is like:

| Cohort Day | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-27 | 5.87 | 4.9 | 2.89 | 1.47 | 1.38 | 0.95 |
| 2020-12-28 | 13.2 | 3.1 | 0.79 | 1.47 | 1.38 | 0.95 |

I'm trying to decompose it in this format:

| day | sum |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-12-27 | 5.87 |
| 2020-12-28 | 4.9 |
| 2020-12-29 | 2.89 |
| 2020-12-30 | 1.47 |
| 2020-12-31 | 1.38 |
| 2020-01-01 | 0.95 |
| 2020-12-28 | 13.2 |
| 2020-12-29 | 3.1 |
| 2020-12-30 | 0.79 |
| 2020-12-31 | 1.47 |
| 2020-01-01 | 1.38 |
| 2020-01-02 | 0.95 |

To achieve that I created an empty dataframe test and then I'm using for loop to create a column with dates at first:

```
    for row in test.itertuples(): 
        test[0:5, 0] = df['Cohort Day'] + df.apply(lambda x: int(str(df.iloc[0, 4:].columns)) for x in df.iteritems())
        test[0:5, 1] = df[0, 1:].transpose()
```

But all I receive is an empty test dataframe.

Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid using looping codes which are slow.  Use fast vectorized Pandas built-in functions whenever possible.

You can transform the dataframe from wide to long by [`.stack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html). Set `day` as `Cohort Day` plus the day offsets 0, 1, ..., 5, as follows:

```
# convert `Cohort Day` to datetime format
df['Cohort Day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Cohort Day'])

# transform from wide to long
df2 = (df.set_index('Cohort Day')
         .rename_axis(columns='day_offset')
         .stack()
         .reset_index(name='sum')
      )

# convert day offsets 0, 1, 2, ..., 5 to timedelta format
df2['day_offset'] = pd.to_timedelta(df2['day_offset'].astype(int), unit='d')

# set up column `day` as the `Cohort Day` + day offsets
df2['day'] = df2['Cohort Day'] + df2['day_offset']

# Get the desired columns
df_out = df2[['day', 'sum']]
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_out)

          day    sum
0  2020-12-27   5.87
1  2020-12-28   4.90
2  2020-12-29   2.89
3  2020-12-30   1.47
4  2020-12-31   1.38
5  2021-01-01   0.95
6  2020-12-28  13.20
7  2020-12-29   3.10
8  2020-12-30   0.79
9  2020-12-31   1.47
10 2021-01-01   1.38
11 2021-01-02   0.95
```